# CSS stopped working after line 150

Tags: child-theme

I'm editing css stylesheet for my childtheme and after 150 lines of code another line of code stopped applying to the web site. When i put the same line of code on the top everything is ok.

Here is a [link to the stylesheet](http://www.s1060731-15009.home-whs.pl/css/style.css) that I'm working on:

```
#wr-promo-title h1 {font-family: 'lora' !important;}  - first line should be on the bottom
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: This is a general CSS question, not a WordPress question

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you've not declared 'lora' in your stylesheet...all I can see is lorabold, lorabold_italic, loraitalic, loraregular. So I imagine that the css is being interpreted as

```
font-family: !important;
```

and although I'm not 100% I'm pretty sure this is what's causing your problem. Try changing

```
#wr-promo-title h1 {font-family: 'lora' !important;}
```

to

```
#wr-promo-title h1 {font-family: 'loraregular' !important;}
```

it's also a good idea to add some fall back incase there is an issue with the font you want to use like

```
font-family: "loraregular" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif !important;
```

Comment: I have got 'lora' property from the css file generated by Fontsquirell so it must be working. It is not first time when i make css and another line of the css code stop applying to the html. When it does i am always going to the top and start making new styles from there. I am confused :/

Comment: Have you tried the answer I gave you? Open the css link you added and hit CTRL + F, now search for 'lora' (without quotes) and tell me where it is declared as a @font-face